# What's the best practice for str/String values in Rust enums?

Tags: string, enums, rust, lifetime

I have this which is really pleasant to the eye, but I'm concerned about its implications:

```
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum SmtpHost {     
    DOMAIN(String),
    IPV4(Ipv4Addr),
    IPV6(Ipv6Addr),
    UNKNOWN { label:String, literal:String },
}
```

I'm filling this up from a PEG grammar which gives me `&str` so all the stringy calls look like this - `SmtpHost::Domain(s.to_string())`

I would like these enums to be the outcome of the parser, like `smtp_parser::host< 'input >(s: 'input & str) -> SmtpHost`

I have also tried the ref approach, but that starts getting clumsy rather soon:

```
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum SmtpHost<'a > {     
    DOMAIN(&'a str),
    IPV4(Ipv4Addr),
    IPV6(Ipv6Addr),
    UNKNOWN { label:&'a str, literal:&'a str },
}
```

So I'm like either / or ... but you know better. Tell me :o)

My [study project for reference](https://github.com/jocutajar/ResistRustNot.SmtpServer/blob/develop/src/smtp.rustpeg)

Comment: Side note: Enum variants in rust are very typically written in `CamelCase`, not `FULLCAPS`. You might have a specific reason to do this, in which case I apologize. But if not, just stick with the convention :)

Comment: `&str` is not owned, so if you want to be able to keep your tokens around after the parser finishes, you probably *have* to use `String`

Comment: Thanks @Kroltan, will do

Comment: @zstewart, do I take it for an answer? I would like these enums to be the outcome of the parser, like `smtp_parser::host< 'input >(s: 'input & str) -> SmtpHost`

Comment: @RobertCutajar-Robajz if you return `SmtpHost` using `&str` with that lifetime parameter then the returned `SmtpHost` would have to have a lifetime which is <= `'input`, since it the signature would have to be: `smtp_parser::host<'input>(s: &'input str) -> SmtpHost<'input>`. Just use `String` unless you have a specific reason that these values should be borrowing part of a different string; it looks to me like they should own the matched values.

Comment: @zstewart, thanks, sounds good. If the lifetime was bound with the input, one would have to consume the enum before letting go of the input which doesn't seem very practical. On the other hand, I don't really get why would I return a mutable string...

Comment: @RobertCutajar-Robajz This is Rust, mutable/immutable is not generally a property of types. Whether the `String` is mutable depends on whether it's stored in a mutable variable. If you use `let host = smtp_parser::host(s);` then the `String` will also be immutable. It is technically possible to construct types which use privacy to enforce immutability always but this is generally unnecessary since you can usually control mutability at the use site rather than the declaration.

Comment: Thank you @zstewart, would you formulate an answer then because I'm quite satisfied :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The critical difference between `&str` and `String` is ownership. `String` is owned, but `&str` is borrowed. If you store a `&str` value, the container's lifetime will be limited to the lifetime of the borrowed string.

If your parser generator produces a parse function with a signature like this:

```
smtp_parser::host<'a>(&'a str) -> SmtpHost<'a>
```

then when it passes you an `&str` for you to use to construct your parse tree/parsed value, it most likely gives you a substring of the input. This means that the `&str` you are storing in your `SmtpHost` enum must have a lifetime shorter than the original input string. And indeed, you can see this in the signature; both the input string and output `SmtpHost` have lifetime parameter `'a`.

This means that your resulting `SmtpHost` cannot outlive the input used to generate it. If the input is a string constant, `&'static str`, that might be fine, but if you get the input from standard in or reading a file, you won't be able to return the `SmtpHost` past the point where the input string is owned.

For example, suppose that you wanted to declare a function that parsed an `SmtpHost` from standard in:

```
fn read_host<'a>() -> SmtpHost<'a> {
    let mut line = String::new();
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    stdin.lock().read_line(&mut line).expect("Could not read line");
    smtp_parser::host(&line)
}
```

You'll get an error saying something like "line does not live long enough". [Here's a trivial example in Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=enum%20SmtpHost%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Example(%26%27a%20str)%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20return_a_value%3C%27a%3E()%20-%3E%20SmtpHost%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20%22hello%20world%22.to_owned()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20SmtpHost%3A%3AExample(%26x)%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0).

So you should use `&str` when you are just borrowing a value from somewhere else which does not need to outlive the source. You should use `String` when you need to have ownership of the value.

For more complex situations where you need to have an owned value but want to be able to use it in multiple places without having many copies of it, for that there's `Rc<T>` and `Rc<RefCell<T>`. But in your case, it sounds like `SmtpHost` should just have ownership of the string it stores.

Comment: Thanks @zstewart, side note, the rust playground link won't pass my browser, try shrinking it, but I get the point.

Comment: @RobertCutajar-Robajz hm. Odd, it seems to work for me. I initially tried to use the link shortener from Rust playground, but StackOverflow apparently doesn't like link shorteners. Unfortunately the full URL includes the complete code of the example... perhaps it's longer than your browser is happy with.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse without copying,
then the signature you'd want is:

```
// Notice that the 'input goes after the &. Syntax.
fn smtp_parser::host<'input>(s: &'input str) -> SmtpHost<'input>;
```

Then you could define your enum like this:

```
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum SmtpHost<'input> {
    DOMAIN(&'input str),
    IPV4(Ipv4Addr),
    IPV6(Ipv6Addr),
    UNKNOWN { label: &'input str, literal: &'input str },
}
```

On the other hand, if this is too awkward in some cases, you sort of do *both* using the `Cow` (copy-on-write) type:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum SmtpHost<'input> {
    DOMAIN(Cow<'input, str>),
    IPV4(Ipv4Addr),
    IPV6(Ipv6Addr),
    UNKNOWN { label: Cow<'input, str>, literal: Cow<'input, str> },
}
```

This is what you want to do if the host parts can sometimes be used directly out of the input, but sometimes needs to be changed before it's usable.

Comment: Thanks for the Cow @notriddle