# Can I declare an enum value that takes a String or &str without needing additional functions?

Tags: string, rust, enums, coercion

I have an enum with a `String`:

```rust
enum MyLovelyEnum {
    Thing(String),
}
```

For tests, I would like to be able to pass in a `&'static str` to avoid `MyLovelyEnum::Thing("abc".to_string)` over and over.

I found that you can do this nicely with structs with a constructor:

```
// From: https://hermanradtke.com/2015/05/06/creating-a-rust-function-that-accepts-string-or-str.html
struct Person {
    name: String,
}

impl Person {
    fn new<S: Into<String>>(name: S) -> Person {
        Person { name: name.into() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let person = Person::new("Herman");
    let person = Person::new("Herman".to_string());
}
```

I know I can use lifetimes or `Cow` as described in [What's the best practice for str/String values in Rust enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054746/whats-the-best-practice-for-str-string-values-in-rust-enums) or I can make my own function.

Is there something close to the example in the blog post for enums? e.g.

```
// this is the kind of thing I am after but this specifically is not correct syntax
enum MyLovelyEnum {
  Thing<S: Into<String>>(S)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to do _exactly_ what the blog post does and make a constructor for your enum?

Comment: As I said I know I can do that, I wonder if something like:



I have an enum with a String:


```
enum MyLovelyEnum {
    Thing<S: Into<String>>(S),
}
```

is possible?

Comment: That's not "like the blog post" though. The blog post creates a constructor associated function. Why don't you want to create one for your enum?

Comment: I apologize for sounding hostile; that's not my intention. I simply don't understand the problem, so I'm asking. You have a solution that **you** state "can do this nicely", so I don't follow why you don't want to use it. Your post doesn't explain what's **wrong** with creating a constructor, either. You ask "Is there something close to the example in the blog post for enums?". You appear to already know that you can create a constructor for the enum, so I don't see how we'd get from what is in the post to anywhere else, so I ask questions.

Comment: I want to know specifically if you can declare an Enum value that takes a String or &str without needing additional functions.

Taking the blog's example I have tried:

```
enum MyLovelyEnum { Thing<S: Into<String>>(S) }
```

Which is not valid. I don't know Rust well enough to say if my attempt at the syntax is wrong but it is possible, or if it's fundamentally impossible. I suspect the later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240177/discussion-between-shepmaster-and-john).

Comment: BTW, if you don't need an owned string, you can use `&str` and `AsRef<str>` instead of `String` and `Into<String>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a generic enum:

```rust
enum MyLovelyEnum<S>
where
    S: Into<String>,
{
    Thing(S),
}

MyLovelyEnum::Thing("a");
MyLovelyEnum::Thing("b".to_string());
```

I likely wouldn't do that in my code, instead opting to create a constructor, much like the blog post you linked:

```rust
enum MyLovelyEnum {
    Thing(String),
}

impl MyLovelyEnum {
    fn thing(s: impl Into<String>) -> Self {
        MyLovelyEnum::Thing(s.into())
    }
}

MyLovelyEnum::thing("a");
MyLovelyEnum::thing("b".to_string());
```

Comment: I would add that with the first approach, _every_ function using this enum will have to call `.into()`, meaning you'll carry the overhead of converting to `String` every time you call a function, which is usually not what you want.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman while the spirit of your comment is true, I'd point out that you can take the `MyLovelyEnum<S>` and convert it into a `MyLovelyEnum<String>` and then pass it down into the rest of your program. Then only the "outer crust" of your API has to deal with the flexibility, the rest can assume a fixed `String`.

Comment: Yes, I meant the API, not the internal details.